# Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am not sure why it is not able to parse the bindings - each of them does contain content. 
This is the error message:

```
Uncaught Exception (js): Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: Users is not defined;
Bindings value: template: { name: 'grid', foreach: Users}
```

**View:**

```
<div data-bind="foreach: RoleTypes">
            <h3><!--ko text: RoleName--><!--/ko--> (<!--ko text: UserCount--><!--/ko-->)</h3>
            <div id="gridView"  data-bind="template: { name: 'grid', foreach: Users}">
                <section id="Images">
                    <section id="users"></section>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var getRoles = function () {
        Ajax.Get({
            Url: ...,
            DataToSubmit: {id: properties.Id },
            DataType: "json",
            OnSuccess: function (roleData, status, jqXHR) {
                // bind role types
                bindModel(roleData);

                Ajax.Get({
                    Url: ...,
                    DataToSubmit: { pageNumber: 1, id: properties.Id },
                    DataType: "json",
                    OnSuccess: function (userData, status, jqXHR) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    };
```

I am not sure what other parts of my javascript to share to help with this but please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Put `foreach` in quotes in your `data-bind` attribute. Some browsers are picky.

Comment: now i am getting that one of items within the viewmodel is not defined. Am i supposed to do a foreach within my second success statement so that i getting information properly?

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Not sure if i did this right since i am getting my info from the database but here is what i put together: http://jsfiddle.net/8C2HP/

Answer (score 1):

The error message means that one or more of the objects in your ViewModel's `RoleTypes` array doesn't have a property called `Users`. Without seeing the code that defines your VM I can only guess why, but is it possible that `Users` is a top-level property rather than a sub-property of each `RoleType`? If so, then you need to replace `Users` with `$root.Users` so Knockout knows where to look for it.

**Update based on comments**

Each element of `RoleTypes` needs to have an `observableArray` property called `Users` which then gets populated with the users for a particular role. Once you do that, you don't have to qualify `Users` with `$root` because it's a property of the current iteration element.

Comment: maybe you can take a look at the fiddle and see how i have things, i had to alter for jsfiddle and put in dummy data cuz i am actually pulling it from the DB: http://jsfiddle.net/8C2HP/

Comment: It's as I thought: `Users` is a top-level property of your VM, so in order to access it from within a `foreach` you have to qualify it with `$root` (when you're inside a `foreach`, names on bindings refer to the properties of the individual elements of the array you're iterating over, not to the main VM).

Comment: I tried add `$root` but i am not getting the results i should be seeing. I would actually like that the PositionTypes be the top-level in which within the Users so i can get users for each position based on content role